# Can I pass an array and a block as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, proc

Currently learning to create blocks and my own version of Array methods. I was wondering if I could pass an array and a block as parameters to a method. Below is the code I am working on and it should be self-explanatory in what it should do but I keep getting an error. Especially with the method call and where I pass the block.

```
def mapper(arr, &prc)
  new_array = []
  arr.length.times do |i|
    new_array << prc.call(arr[i])
  end
  new_array
end

mapper([1,2,3,4], {|i| i * 2})
```

Comment: Block literals go outside the parenthesis, not inside. `a.map() { |i| ... }` not `a.map({ |i| ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by passing the block outside the parentheses (adjacent to the method call):

```
p mapper([1, 2, 3, 4]) { |index| index * 2 }
# [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Otherwise it'll result in a syntax error. Ruby won't know where the block is being passed.

As a side note, you can also define only the array as a needed argument, and then yield the block being passed:

```
def mapper(arr)
  arr.size.times.map do |i|
    yield(arr[i])
  end
end

p mapper([1, 2, 3, 4]) { |index| index * 2 }
# [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't thought of it that way. I am learning procs and lambdas so I needed to pass it through the method. yielding sounds useful too but not for these purposes.

Comment: What do you mean, "not for these purposes"? This is exactly when you'd use it.